# FreeBSD setup RTL8187SE wireless NIC

Tags: wifi, freebsd, pci, realtek

I am running FreeBSD 10. My wireless card is:

```
none1@pci0:9:0:0:   class=0x028000 card=0x818210ec chip=0x819910ec rev=0x22 hdr=0x00
    vendor     = 'Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.'
    device     = 'RTL8187SE Wireless LAN Controller'
    class      = network
```

I followed the instructions at https://www.dan.me.uk/blog/2010/01/25/ndis-wifi-drivers-in-freebsd-project-evil/

I was able to successfully create and load a ko file from the WindXP driver for my NIC. I did not get the output:

```
ndis0: <Realtek RTL8191SE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E NIC> port 0×3000-0x30ff mem 0xfa000000-0xfa003fff irq 17 at device 0.0 on pci3
ndis0: [ITHREAD]
ndis0: NDIS API version: 5.1
```

Or anything similar to that. When I do `ifconfig` I do not see the ndis device. Can someone please help me with setting up this WNIC? Am I missing a step? I do not see the device at all.

Steps I took:

1. Downloaded WinXP driver
2. `ndisgen /drv/net8187Se.inf /drv/rtl8187Se.sys`
3. Moved the `rtl***_sys.ko` file to `/boot/modules`
4. Edited `/etc/rc.conf`

   ```
   hostname="carbonpc"
   ifconfig_alc0="DHCP"
   ifconfig_alc0_ipv6="inet6 accept_rtadv"
   sshd_enable="YES"
   moused_enable="YES"
   powerd_enable="YES"
   # Set dumpdev to "AUTO" to enable crash dumps, "NO" to disable
   dumpdev="AUTO"
   wlans_ndis0="wlan0"
   ifconfig_wlan0="WPA DHCP"
   ```

---

```
# kldstat
Id Refs Address            Size     Name
 1   18 0xffffffff80200000 15f0430  kernel
 2    1 0xffffffff817f1000 5dcf8    rtl8187Se_sys.ko
 3    2 0xffffffff8184f000 19b48    if_ndis.ko
 4    3 0xffffffff81869000 398c0    ndis.ko
```

ifconfig does not show any kind of wlan0.

Comment: Can you show the content of some of the files you have to update and the rough steps you followed, obviously not asking you to recreate the whole article you've linked to, but a summary and the output of the various stages may help.  Also, what output *did* you get?

Comment: @EightBitTony I have made the requested updates.

Comment: To be sure, that article is over four years old. Not that I know it makes a difference but be aware.